$X$ = $\bigoplus_pX_i$ is Banach if each $X_i$ is Banach
If $1\leq p<\infty$, define $$X =\bigoplus_pX_i :=\left\{x\in\prod_iX_i:||x|| := \left[\sum_i||x(i)||^p\right]^{\frac{1}{p}}<\infty\right\}$$
and if $p = \infty$ instead define the norm to be $||x||_\infty = \sup_i||x(i)||$. I'm trying to show that if each $X_i$ is Banach, then the space $X$ must be Banach as well. Here's what I have so far, I'd like for it to be checked.
Case 1: $1\leq p<\infty$.
Let $\{x_n\}$ be a cauchy sequence in $X$, then $\exists N$ s.t $n,m\geq N\implies ||x_n-x_m||<\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$.
$$||x_n-x_m|| = \left[\sum_i||x_n(i)-x_m(i)||^p\right]^{\frac{1}{p}}<\varepsilon\implies \sum_i||x_n(i)-x_m(i)||^p < \varepsilon^p \implies ||x_n(i)-x_m(i)||^p < \varepsilon^p$$
for all $i\in I$, so $||x_n(i)-x_m(i)||<\varepsilon$ and hence $\{x_n(i)\}$ is cauchy in each $X_i$, so $x_n(i)\to x(i)\in X_i$. Define $x = (\lim x_n(i))_{i\in I}$ and claim that $x_n\to x$. pf: Let $n\geq N$. Then
$$||x_n-x|| =  \left[\sum_i||x_n(i)-x(i)||^p\right]^{\frac{1}{p}}$$
but since $x_n(i)\to x(i)$, $||x_n(i)-x(i)||^p \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, hence $||x_n-x||<\varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$. Now w.t.s that $x\in X$. Since $||x-x_n|| <\varepsilon$, we have
$$||x||<||x_n||+\varepsilon <\infty$$
since $x_n\in X$, so $||x_n||<\infty$ and $||x_n||+\varepsilon<\infty$. Thus $x\in X$.
Case 2: $p=\infty$.
Once again, let $\{x_n\}$ be cauchy in $X$. Then $$||x_n-x_m|| = \sup_i||x_n(i)-x_m(i)||\implies ||x_n(i)-x_m(i)||<\varepsilon \ \forall i\in I$$
so $\{x_n(i)\}$ is cauchy and $x_n(i)\to x(i)$. Let $x = (\lim x_n(i))_{i\in I}$, clearly $x_n\to x$. Now to show $x\in X$, simply note that $x(i)\in X_i\implies ||x(i)||<\infty$ for all $i$, so
$$||x|| = \sup_i||x(i)||<\infty \implies x\in X$$
and we are done.

Your proof for $p<\infty$ is not correct as you haven't justified $x\in X.$ I suggest you follow the proof of completness of $\ell^p$.

This site is not a proof checking machine. Please check out the [tag:solution-verification] tag description: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so. This should not be the only tag for a question, and should not be used to circumvent site policies regarding duplication.

Thank you, I'll be more specific next time


$1 \leqslant p < \infty$
$\|x_n(i) - x(i) \|^p \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, hence $\| x_n - x \| < \varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$.

This requires justification, especially that the inequality will be true starting from some $N$ and you provide no hint how to find such $N$.

$p = \infty$
clearly $x_n \to x$

I don't know if this is so clear, but if you feel you know how to prove this part, it's fine.

$\| x(i) \| < \infty$ for all $i \in I$, so $\| x \| < \infty$

This is wrong, there exist unbounded sequences $(a_i)_{i \in I}$ of real (finite) numbers.

Thank you, for the first error: is it sufficient to say that there is an $N_i$ for each cauchy sequence $x_n(i)$ such that $||x_n(i)-x(i)||^p<\varepsilon$ for all $n>N_i$, then apply zorns lemma to find a (finite) maximal element $N$ on the set of all such $N_i$'s?
And for the last one, I thought since $x(i)$ is just one element in $X_i$ then $||x(i)||$ must be finite. Then by choosing the sup over all such finite $||x(i)||$ $||x||$ must also be finite. Is that wrong?


A maximal $N_i$ may not exist, trying to use Zorn's lemma is completely off track. And even if $| x_n(i) - x(i) |^p < \varepsilon$ were simultaneously true for sufficiently large $n$, this still wouldn't imply that $| x_n - x | < \varepsilon$. You have to use the fact that $(x_n)$ is Cauchy again. 2. Consider $I = \mathbb{N}$ and $| x(i) | = i$ for $i \in I$. Then each $| x(i) |$ is finite, but $\sup_{i \in I} | x(i) |$ doesn't exist (it's infinite). Here also you need to use that $(x_n)$ is Cauchy.

